# Does Glide queue up every image request? Recyclerview loads are very slow when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have been seeing very long load times for images in our app using Glide 3.6 + a RecyclerView using a GridLayoutManager. The images are all around 20kb-40kb. It seems that glide queues up all the requests which causes the images to take quite awhile to load once you start scrolling further down the list. I've attached the logs from the GenericRequest class.

```
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.170291 this: 249721749
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.36724999999999997 this: 249721749
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.763083 this: 249721749
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.041249999999999995 this: 991315424
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.15479199999999999 this: 991315424
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.30008399999999996 this: 991315424
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.499959 this: 991315424
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.060584 this: 1029510845
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.200625 this: 1029510845
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.39233399999999996 this: 1029510845
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.670084 this: 1029510845
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.048374999999999994 this: 516458536
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.188666 this: 516458536
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.379916 this: 516458536
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.654083 this: 516458536
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 1012.49325 size: 2.18359375 fromCache: false this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.073833 this: 356666200
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.240667 this: 356666200
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.460792 this: 356666200
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.780708 this: 356666200
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.064583 this: 347417463
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.242583 this: 347417463
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.45758299999999996 this: 347417463
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.7521249999999999 this: 347417463
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.142833 this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.38966599999999996 this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.703708 this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 1.851125 this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ Got onSizeReady in 0.056957999999999995 this: 634418527
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished setup for calling load in 0.21787499999999999 this: 634418527
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished onSizeReady in 0.443083 this: 634418527
V/GenericRequest﹕ finished run method in 0.7567499999999999 this: 634418527
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 3443.041335 size: 2.18359375 fromCache: false this: 249721749
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4110.604794 size: 3.8623809814453125 fromCache: false this: 1054166306
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 3824.033544 size: 3.8623809814453125 fromCache: false this: 991315424
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 3773.0562109999996 size: 3.8623809814453125 fromCache: false this: 1029510845
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4542.90796 size: 2.18359375 fromCache: false this: 516458536
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4171.866168 size: 3.8623809814453125 fromCache: false this: 634418527
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4474.170752 size: 3.8623809814453125 fromCache: false this: 356666200
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4496.104085 size: 2.18359375 fromCache: false this: 671303046
V/GenericRequest﹕ Resource ready in 4814.625126999999 size: 2.18359375 fromCache: false this: 347417463
```

Was wondering if anyone could provide some insight into what the issue might be. Maybe its the time it takes to resize to the view? I am using `match_parent` for the width of the view and a fixed height of about `200dp`.

Images are loaded using

```
Glide.with(fragmentContext)
          .load(imageUrl)
          .centerCrop()
          .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
          .into(viewHolder.productImage);
```

XML

```
<ImageView
      android:id="@+id/product_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/product_image_height" (208dp)
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:background="@color/placeholder_bg"
      />
```

EDIT: As per @VladimirMironov comment. I've updated with the increased pool and clearing the pending loads when a view is recycled.  This seems to have helped a bit when scrolling fast.  Does providing an override or not using "match_parent" for the view provide any benefits when in comes to view measuring? There are still cases where a view wont show for almost 5 secs.

Comment: There are two things you can try to improve the performance:
1. Cancel downloading request in `RecyclerView.Adapter.onViewRecycled` (via `Glide.clear` call)
2. Increase `ViewHolder`s pool size via `recycler.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 2 * numColumns)`

Comment: @VladimirMironov interesting didnt know about these i'll give it a shot

Comment: @VladimirMironov i've edited my post with some additional info

Answer (score 1):

**Add following lines and you will see the improvement**

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
yourAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);//recycler adapter
```

**override onViewRecycled() & clear previous Glide request**

```
Glide.with(imageHolder.preview.getContext()).clear(imageHolder.preview);
```